# Does this piecewise function contradict the fact that all differentiable functions are continuous?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I learned that all differentiable functions are continuous. Why does the following equation not violate this rule:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2+3 \quad &\text{when } x>1  \\ x^2 \quad &\text{when }x\le 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: The derivative at $x = 1$ does not exist as $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x) - 1}{x-1}$ does not exist. In particular, the limit from above.

Comment: That function is neither continuous nor differentiable at $x = 1$.

Comment: I am confused the derivative of x^2+3 = 2x and the derivative of x^2 = 2x where is the error

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Away from the domain point $x=1$, you are indeed correct that the function is differentiable and continuous. This single point is the only exception. The derivative doesn't exist there because the limit of the difference quotient only exists from one side. The whole problem is that the value of the function there can't match both the left and right side since you have introduced a jump discontinuity there.

Comment: but the two side both equal 2x do they not

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $x^2+3$ and the derivative of $x^2$ are both $2x$, but your function is neither of these functions. To be Socratic, let me ask you this: Do you think a piecewise function, where each piece is differentiable and has the same derivative, is differentiable?

Comment: usually yes but, but I see that there just as many exepetions

Comment: Remember, when we say "a function $f$ is differentiable" what we mean to say is that for each $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the limit $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$ exists and is a real number for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. What is confusing here is that this fact is *not necessarily* implied by the fact that the **derivative function** $f^{\prime}$ is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In your example, you are correct: $f^{\prime}(x) = 2x$ for all $x$ but that does not mean that the derivative limit (above) exists for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$. The limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+}\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}$$
does not exist.

Comment: Great use of algebra to demonstrate the fact that the limit of the difference quotient does not exist. What might add to one's conceptual understanding is a geometric explanation: the slope of the line between $\bigl(1, f(1)\bigr)$ and $\bigl(1+h, f(1+h)\bigr)$ increases without bound (the line gets steeper) as $h\to 0$. See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/setxr2sr6o) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

This function is not differentiable at $x=1$, nor is it continuous there. That's why.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer demonstrated *why* the function is not differentiable at 1. Also, the fact that it is discontinuous there is unnecessary. The OP knows it is discontinuous, which is why they asked the question in the first place: it was an attempt at a counterexample.